# Angular HttpClient post not sending

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

Probably just a silly mistake somewhere but i cant seem to pinpoint the cause. The function is being called (verified by the console log) but for some reason neither the error log or the success log print out afterwards. The back end is not receiving the post request, so why is the error log not showing anything?

```
getBooks(): Observable <FormData | null> {
  let request = new FormData();
  request.append('action', "GetBooks");

  console.log("Function has been called");

  return this.http.post('http://localhost/Projects/Website/PHP/index.php', request).pipe(
    map((returned) => {
      console.log("Here I parse 'returned'");

      let books = new FormData();

      return books;
  }, (error) => {
    console.log('Error! ', error);
    return null;
  }));
}
```

Comment: Call the method with getBooks().subscribe()

Comment: @MolikMiah why?

Comment: Sorry for lack of information im typing on a mobile. When you set up a method like this you are returning an observable. Think of it as provisioning a http request. To actually make the call and get the data returned you must subscribe to it. Please have a look at angular docs for http and they will provide a better explanation

Comment: This page will explain it https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to call .subscribe() so your method will be used.

since your work with an observable, subscribe is the function that "listen" to any data coming from the observable, which actually execute the code.

```
     var res=null;
     this.http.post('http://localhost/Projects/Website/PHP/index.php', 
     request).subscribe(data => {
          res=data;
          },
          error => {
           ...
          },
          () => {
          ...
          }
          return res;
```